# Postgres reports coltype -7 (BIT) but qualified-name bool

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, boolean, bit

I read the type of a column using the jdbc metadata.

Using this java-code

```
columns = metadata.getColumns(catalogName, schema.getName(), table.getName(), "%");
while (columns.next()) {
  final String fqtn = columns.getString(6);
  int type = columns.getInt(5);
  LOG.fine("Column '" + table.getName() + "." + columnName + "' is type: " + type + " and of fqtn:" + fqtn + "!");
}
```

I log this output:

```
Column 'BUILD_RESULT.finished' is type: -7 and of fqtn:bool!
```

I look into `java.sql.Types` and looking for -7 and found BIT

[image]

So type -7 is `BIT` but name is reported `bool`.

There is a difference between BIT and BOOL:

- BIT can be `0` or `1`
- BOOL can be `true` or `false`.

Why is bit (-7) reported when there is a better matching type 16 (BOOLEAN) in `java.sql.Types`?

I installed a sql-manager and inspect the field BUILD_RESULT.finished like this:

[image]

It is boolean, not bit. Why is postgres jdbc telling me it is a BIT?

### EDIT: Add version of jdbc-jar

I do not have the jar-name but I have the Manifest's info:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1455914805118
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_66
Built-By: vladimirsitnikov
Bundle-Activator: org.postgresql.osgi.PGBundleActivator
Bundle-Copyright: Copyright (c) 2003-2015, PostgreSQL Global Development
  Group
Bundle-Description: Java JDBC 4.1 (JRE 7+) driver for PostgreSQL databas
 e
Bundle-DocURL: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/
Bundle-License: http://www.postgresql.org/about/licence/
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver JDBC41
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.postgresql.jdbc41
Bundle-Vendor: PostgreSQL Global Development Group
Bundle-Version: 9.4.1208.jre7
```

And `select version()` said: PostgreSQL 9.4.25 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.4.25-1.pgdg18.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

Comment: Most likely the database doesn't differentiate them on that level. I'm assuming the driver doesn't do anything to those values (too lazy to look, but from my experience with the Postgres driver it's a safe bet), only passes you what the db is replying with, so jdbc is not to blame.

Comment: What is the version of the driver you are using and what is the Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added the jdbc-driver manifest information and server-info.

Comment: @Kayaman, [bit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html)  and [boolean](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) are two entirely  different types in Postgres. This is something being done above the database level.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the driver. The current driver returns the same. You could log an  issue in their [tracker](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc). But you should really upgrade your versions. Your driver version is about 6 years old and Postgres 9.4 is no longer maintained since 2 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is unsolved since 7 years:  https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/367

Credits to a @a_horse_with_no_name